# Can't initiate Stellar.js from div

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to implement Stellar.js (http://markdalgleish.com/projects/stellar.js/) to a site that I'm developing. I realised that I need to enclose the parallax scrolling inside a container instead of using window/body in order for it to work on an iPad (considering the viewport) and that's where I run into a problem; the script doesn't seem to initiate correctly.

Here's the structure I've setup on the site -

HTML

```
    <header></header>
        <!-- keeping this content outside of #content because of a prefixed alignment -->

        <div id="content">

        <section id="example" data-stellar-background-ratio="1">
            <img src="example-1.png" data-stellar-ratio="2" data-stellar-offset="-25">
            <img src="example-2.png" data-stellar-ratio="3" data-stellar-offset="-50">
            <img src="example-3.png" data-stellar-ratio="4" data-stellar-offset="0">
        </section>

    </div>
```

CSS

```
    #content {
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

section {

        background-attachment: fixed;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        position: relative;
    }
        img:first-child {
            position: absolute;
            top: 0;
            left: 300px;
        }
        img:nth-child(2) {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            top: 0;
            right: 150px;
        }
        img:nth-child(3) {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 99;
            top: 0;
            left: 100px;
        }
```

JavaScript

```
 $('#content').stellar({
        horizontalScrolling: false
    });
```

I can see that the parallax images inside the section get display: none, but other than that the script doesn't seem to be running. I get no JS errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm thinking it might have something to do with you using `position: absolute` and not giving the div any with.

Did you check the size of your `#content` div? Or does stellar handle this too?

Comment: No idea what's really required. I've tried dozens of approaches, giving up on this issue.